# insetting on 'facet_grid'ed and 'grid.arrange'ed plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a 2 faceted ggplot objects, and grid.arrange them in two columns (grid.arrange columns). In the second column, in each faceted member, I would like to inset a histogram. The data sources for the two columns are also different. So far I can only manage to grid arrange two faceted ggplot object. I need to know how to inset in the second column of grid.arrange.

Following code is a very simplistic representation of my data.

```
#Two data sources (d1,d2). They will have even different facetting parameters as well, 
#but here I have simplified it.

d1<-data.frame(FacetRow=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',4)),
           FacetCol=rep(c(rep('c',2),rep('d',2)),2),
           X=rep(c(1,2),4),
           Y=runif(8)
           )
d2<-data.frame(FacetRow=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',4)),
               FacetCol=rep(c(rep('c',2),rep('d',2)),2),
               X=rep(c(1,2),4),
               Y=runif(8)
)

#GGPlot object for First column of grid.arrange
g.col.1<-ggplot(data=d1,aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_line()+facet_grid(FacetRow~FacetCol)
#GGPlot object for Second column of grid.arrange
g.col.2<-ggplot(data=d2,aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_line()+facet_grid(FacetRow~FacetCol)
grid.arrange(g.col.1,g.col.2,ncol=2)
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NTDT.png) is how it looks. So I just need to know how to inset a histogram of values in each of the (e,f,g)X(h,i) plots.

Further, I need to keep plotting this on different pages of a pdf by varying the d1 and d2. So I think I can only print the finally created ggplot object once, and then change d1 & d2 and then print again, and so on.

Will be grateful if anyone can help with this problem.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`annotation_custom` would be convenient, unfortunately it's not meant to place different grobs in different panels (don't ask me). This minimal change works around that,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
annotation_custom2 <- function (grob, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, data) 
  {
    layer(data = data, stat = StatIdentity, position = PositionIdentity, 
          geom = ggplot2:::GeomCustomAnn,
          inherit.aes = TRUE, params = list(grob = grob, 
                                            xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, 
                                            ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))
  }

inset <- qplot(rnorm(10))

p1 <- ggplot(data=d1,aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_line()+facet_grid(FacetRow~FacetCol)
p2 <- ggplot(data=d2,aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_line()+facet_grid(FacetRow~FacetCol) +
  annotation_custom2(ggplotGrob(inset), data=data.frame(FacetRow="b", FacetCol = "c", X=1, Y=1),
                     xmin=-Inf, xmax=1.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=0.6)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Note: you could use plyr to generate those annotation layers automatically, e.g.

```
library(plyr)

insets <- dlply(d2, c("FacetRow", "FacetCol"), function(d){
  annotation_custom2(grob = ggplotGrob(qplot(d$Y) + 
                                         ggtitle(sprintf("col: %s\nrow: %s", 
                                                         unique(d$FacetCol), unique(d$FacetRow)))), 
                     data = data.frame(X=min(d$X), Y=min(d$Y), 
                                       FacetRow=unique(d$FacetRow), 
                                       FacetCol=unique(d$FacetCol)), 
                     xmin=-Inf, xmax=1.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=0.6)
})

p1 <- ggplot(data=d1,aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_line()+facet_grid(FacetRow~FacetCol)
p2 <- ggplot(data=d2,aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_line()+facet_grid(FacetRow~FacetCol) +
  insets

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution Baptiste, but can you let me know how to calculate the histogram of values (Y values) inside each panel (that is separately for each FacetRows and FacetCols combination)? Right now we are using a `qplot(rnorm(10))` as a constant histogram for each panel. Is there a way to infer these automatically from the dataframe.